# Understanding type in Ocaml

Tags: types, ocaml

Is there a way to know what type of something is in Ocaml when you enter it in ocaml.

For example, in python, if you put: "type(3)" you got int.
Another example, if you put: type("hello") you got string.

What is the equivalent in ocaml?

Answer (score 3):

Type information is not present in compiled OCaml code. So there's no function you can call to get the type of a value.

Note that the type of a given value in OCaml is fixed, i.e., it can't change. So there's no real need to test types while the code is running. The type at compile time is the permanent type of the value.

The OCaml REPL (often called "toplevel") does have type information. If you type a value at the prompt, it will tell you the type:

```
# 3;;
- : int = 3
# "hello";;
- : string = "hello"
#
```

If you have code in a file "mycode.ml" you can load it into the REPL and the interpreter will print the types of all the top-level names:

```
# #use "mycode.ml";;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
```

These are very simple solutions. You can also set yourself up with an IDE that shows the type of whatever is under the cursor as you edit your code.

Comment: Thank you for that. I asked because I am a beginner at Ocaml and do not understand what  "val add : ’a -> ’a set -> ’a set" is when applied to "let a: ______= add 3 [ ]"

Comment: This is a different question, really. OCaml types are specified with a very systematic little sub-language. So `'a -> 'a set -> 'a set` has a certain very clear meaning. You can read about OCaml function types near the end of this page: https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/basics.html

Comment: For completion i would mention that using [merlin](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin) from your prefered text editor is the way of doing it on a source code file. This might be more practical than going through a REPL when working on a project .